# Electron: Custom Titlebar: Buttons don't change their CSS properties back to normal (after mouse hover) when the cursor leaves the app

Tags: html, css, electron, titlebar

[image: The behaviour of the buttons after the cursor leaves the app]

Greetings! This is my second time posting today, but that's how people learn, right?
Anyway! I am creating an app with Electron and I want to create a custom title bar. I have been successful but there is a small detail that kind of bothers me. I want the buttons to change their opacity when the mouse hovers them but when the cursor leaves the app after hovering the buttons, they don't change. Instead, I have to go to the app again, hover the button again and finally see the right behaviour.
Is there a way to fix this? It's not that fatal, but I am trying to make my app look good and pleasant to the eye as much as I can!

HTML:

```
<div class="titlebar">
    <div class="dragzone"></div>
    <h1>Dashboard - Wealm</h1>
    <button id="closeApp">x</button>
    <button id="minApp">-</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.titlebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 29px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 50;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

.titlebar .dragzone {
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 990px;
    height: 29px;
}

.titlebar h1 {
    float: left;
    opacity: 0.85;
    margin: 4px 0 0 43.5%;
    font-family: Jost-400-Book;
    font-size: 12pt;
}

.titlebar #closeApp {
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0.55;
    float: right;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-family: Eight One;
    font-size: 18pt;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.titlebar #minApp {
    font-weight: bold;
    opacity: 0.55;
    float: right;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-family: Eight One;
    font-size: 18pt;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.titlebar #closeApp:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.titlebar #minApp:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: "but that's how people learn, right?" yup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great news! I did found a solution! What I did - First of all, I replaced the content inside the buttons with paragraphs. It's the same text but in paragraph tags. I set the `overflow` property of the buttons to `visible`, in order to be able to set the height of the buttons to 0 without hiding the paragraphs themselves. Then I just played around with margins. It's up to you!

```
.titlebar #closeApp {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: none;
    float: right;
    opacity: 0.55;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-family: Eight One;
    font-size: 18pt;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.titlebar #closeApp p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: -5.45px;
}

.titlebar #minApp {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: none;
    float: right;
    opacity: 0.55;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    font-family: Eight One;
    font-size: 18pt;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 8px
}

.titlebar #minApp p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: -5.45px;
}
```

Have a great day! Let me know if you have a question or the solution just doesn't work for you!